# Identify the destination whose bamount is higher than the sum of bamount

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select destname from destination where destinationid in (select destinationid from booking group by destinationid having bookamount> (select avg(bookamount) from booking));
```

After executing it shows me the wrong output. After that I tried this one. With the help of this query I can get the average amount of each destination and now i need to know the destination whose single booking amount is greater than average amount done that location:

```
select destinationid, avg(bookamount) from booking group by destinationid;
```

but i need an advice to do it correctly.

I tried hard coding but i know its the wrong way to do it:

Comment: You don't explain what the "right" output is.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to find bookings that are over the average amount for the destination?

```
SELECT b.*
FROM booking b
    INNER JOIN (
        -- Make a subquery (think of it as a helper table) to look up the average booking amount for each destination.
        SELECT destination_id, AVG(book_amount) AS book_amount_avg FROM booking GROUP BY destination_id
    ) AS da
        ON b.destination_id = da.destination_id
WHERE b.book_amount > da.book_amount_avg
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this then?

```
SELECT d.destination_id, d.name
FROM destination d
    INNER JOIN (
        -- Total value bookings for each destination.
        SELECT destination_id, SUM(booking_amount) AS booking_amount_destination_sum 
        FROM booking 
        GROUP BY destination_id
    ) AS dt
        ON d.destination_id = dt.destination_id
    INNER JOIN (
        -- Averave value of bookings for each location.
        SELECT location_id, AVG(book_amount) AS book_amount_location_avg 
        FROM booking 
        GROUP BY location_id
    ) AS la
        ON d.location_id = la.location_id
WHERE dt.booking_amount_destination_sum > da.book_amount_location_avg
```